# Get Closest Date in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hi i am trying to get nearest Date here is my code

```
 SELECT schedule_date  FROM  schedule_table WHERE schedule_date > '2012-06-07' and   event_id='23' ORDER BY schedule_date ASC
       LIMIT 1
```

here actual table  schedule_date  contain 2012-06-07 00:00:00 like this.But i Check '2012-06-07' so

i get output like this `2012-06-07 06:53:57` that mean same date came but i need `2012-06-08 04:53:57`
i think here we need to check this condition using like operator

how could i use like operator in this query to get closest date in sql.
Thanks for advance.

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the input? What is the desired output? What do you get instead?

Comment: Why do you need a like operator on a date field? It's a date field, not a string. Are you trying to get the date closest to the date you supplied whether in the past or future?

Comment: when supplied date is string user send me current date only not time so how can i check this condition

Comment: Do you mean you need the next closest date not including the date you are supplying? What if you added a day prior to the SQL query? Or when you supply the date in the query, set the time with the date as 23:59:59. So in your example above, either it would be 2012-06-07 23:59:59 or altered via php... 2012-06-08 00:00:00

Comment: @Foobar yes i need next closet date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic case of matching date value with a datetime field type. What you need is the earliest time value within the same date. Possibly your data contains multiple rows with data on same date but different time values. You should use the following:

```
SELECT schedule_date  FROM  schedule_table WHERE date(schedule_date) >= '2012-06-07' and   event_id='23' ORDER BY schedule_date ASC
       LIMIT 1
```

The date() function is explained in MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Answer (score 2):

Query: sort by date, greater than / equal to 2012-06-07, limit 1

the record returned should be your desired row

Note: Do not use LIKE operator. It is unnecessary here because it is meant for searching for text matches within a given string. Which is clearly not what your query is trying to accomplish.

Comment: in above query i need greater date

Comment: @FahimParkar OP thinks they need the `LIKE` operator, but they most definitely do *not*.

Comment: @Suresh Switch it to greater than or equal to. :)

Comment: @MetalFrog i try greater than or equal to same result here i think we compare string to date  SELECT schedule_date  FROM  schedule_table WHERE schedule_date > '2012-06-07 06:53:57' and   event_id='23' ORDER BY schedule_date ASC
       LIMIT 1 when i compare like it works fine my problem compare '2012-06-07'

Comment: @Suresh try: schedule_date >= '2012-06-07 00:00:00'

Comment: @Kristian same result i think we need to check using like operator

Comment: @Suresh LIKE is meant for checking string matches in text. trust me, its not the LIKE operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions